# rank of the expectation not matching

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, random-matrices

For a matrix H of size $M\times N$ with zero mean random entries with variance $\beta$, I am trying to find $$\mathbb{E}\{HVV^H H^H\}=\beta tr(VV^H) I_M,$$where V is of size $N\times d$ with $d<N$.

The problem is that the rank of left side is $d$, whereas right side has the rank of $M$.

Can someone inform me the correct way to get the value of the expectation?

Comment: The possible answer I found: 
Expectation is like averaging, so $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i x_i^H -> \mathbb{E}{xx^H}$, that is, summation increases the rank. Thus, solution may not be rank 1 in this case.

Comment: Using your formula, the rank of the left hand side (the expectation) *is* the rank of the right hand side, i.e. $M$. The rank of the random matrix on the left hand side is random, so it is not always $d$.

Comment: @JKL: $M>N>d$, so the rank inside the expectation is always less than equal to $d$. 
And it has been proven in papers that a matrix derived from continuous Gaussian distribution is almost surely full-rank, thus rank in not random if $H$ and $V$ are full rank.

Comment: Just to clarify, the rank of a *random* matrix (e.g. $H V V^* H^*$ in this instance, since $H$ is random) remains random, even if it has full rank almost surely (on an event of full probability). I understand your first point now. Another insight is that the expectation is taken elementwise, so the resulting matrix (on the right-hand side) can have larger rank.